# Background image for button getting stretched

Tags: android, button, android-drawable

In my layout I have a button with  a background image. When  I set the width and height both to `wrap_content`, the background gets stretched. But when I use the same value for `dp` to set to width and height I get the expected result. Why is it happening?

The image is originally circle.

```
           <Button
            android:id="@+id/captureButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_capture" />
```

When set to wrap content for height and width

[image]

When set to 80dp for height and width

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate it? And the background I've set is that red circle only. I'm using it as a shutter button for my camera

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `background` is meant to fill the container.
But, since Button inherits from TextView, you can use a **compound drawable**.

Something like so:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/captureButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_capture"
/>
```

Alternative: Using a TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/captureButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_capture"
    android:clickable="true"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, it works now, but it now has rectangle shape around it, just like an usual button. How to remove it?

Comment: You could set a custom style. Alternatively, you can use a TextView instead of a Button. And set its `android:clickable` property to `true`

Comment: Okay, giving it a try

Comment: I often use TextViews in place of Buttons.

Answer (score 1):

With your xml layout of Button like above, you will have a Button with an empty text (""), you should notice that the default padding left and right of a Button is not same as top and bottom. 
Hence Button with empty text will have a shape of rectangle, not a square, so the background will be stretched.

In the case you fix the width and height, it will make sure that the button always the size you want (a square), so background will display perfectly.

Comment: I see. How can I display it perfectly? I don't want to set dp cause I want to use different versions of the background to support multiple screen

Comment: You can create a dimension in dimens.xml, like that http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/samples/CustomNotifications/res/values-sw720dp-land/dimens.html. Then use this value by @dimens/captureSize for both width and height. With dimens.xml, you can specify the different size for multiple screen :)

Comment: Another solution, you can try using ImageButton, it is more suitable then Button in your case. But you should also define the dimension for multiple screen :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) or set a fixed width and height for your button